# ошибка синхронизации gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build

При синхронизации проекта высвечивается ошибка такого рода:

**Build**

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'GK_Tracker'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0-release-764.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
     Required by:
         project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

**build.gradle(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0-release-764'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Как я понял, это означает, что репозиторий либо не найден, либо содержит ошибку. Как можно исправить данное недоразумение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Репозиторий `jcenter()` [объявлен устаревшим](https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown)

Замените его на `maven`

Например так:

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
```